# Dropdownmenu-Limitation to 1

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I just wanted to ask you if it is possible to limit the amount of Dropdownmenus opened at the same time. In the following you can see the code of my dropdownmenu. I want to include a funtion that limits the amount of dropdownmenus opened to 1. So if no menu is opened it should just open normal and if a menu is already open it should close this one and open the selected one.

```
<script>

var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdownbtn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}

</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As per my knowledge default behavior is to open one dropdown at a time. Then why you need to do this?

Comment: Right now you can open multiple dropdowns and when you open all the dropdowns it will overlap the page. Sure it is default behavior to open one at a time but you never know and if someone does it, it looks ugly in my perspective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ".dropdownbtn" in place makes it more complicated. What do you think of customization?

```
<nav>
  <ul class="my-nav">
    <li>
      <details class="dropdownbtn">
        <summary>First</summary>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </details>
    </li>
    <li>
      <details class="dropdownbtn">
        <summary>Second</summary>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </details>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And than your logic:

```
var nav = document.querySelector('.my-nav');
nav.addEventListener('toggle', (event) => {
  
  // Only run if the dropdown is open
  if(!event.target.open) {
    return;
  }

  // Get all other open dropdowns and close them
  var dropdowns = nav.querySelectorAll('.dropdownbtn[open]');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(dropdowns, (dropdown) => {
    if(dropdown === event.target) { 
      return;
    }
    dropdown.removeAttribute('open');
  });

}, true);
```

I have this solution for you on [codepen](https://codepen.io/agandurmisevic/pen/dydpMOV).